# Vulkan GLSL shaders in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glsl, vulkan

I'm using a [shader transpiler tool](https://github.com/septag/glslcc) called 'glslcc' and it supports transpiling into glsl. However I think the GLSL outputs are Vulkan GLSL since it contains things like the following but I might be wrong.

```
layout(std140) uniform u_Test
{
    vec4 test;
} _34;
```

Will this shader work in OpenGL? If not is there a way to convert from this format to something else so it can be loaded in OpenGL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [Uniform Block](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)#Uniform_blocks) that can of course be used with OpenGL (see also  [Uniform Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object)). There is no Vulkan exclusive declaration in this code. The [Layout Qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)) `std140` was introduced with OpenGL 3.1. See [The OpenGL® Shading Language, Version 4.60.7](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have a few questions: 1. Is there anything in Vulkan GLSL that is not compatible with OpenGL? 2. If I want to set the `test` vector4, do I use the normal `glUniform4f()` on the `test` variable or do I have to set it using the `u_Test` uniform?

Comment: @SunnyMonster 1. Of course there are differences. See [The OpenGL® Shading Language, Version 4.60.7](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html). and search for "Vulkan". 2. See [Uniform Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object) and [Interface Block (GLSL) - Buffer backed](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)#Buffer_backed)